# Grafana - It's possible to see two overlapping lines at the same time in Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm still a little newbie with all this Grafana stuff but trying my best.

I'm using Prometheus to collect some data from a service and I want to display some counters in Grafana. I currently have this panel:
[image]

Although it may not look like it in this graph there are two overlapping lines as I have two instances of the development server being monitored. At around 12:30 we can see how one of the instances registers an event and its respective pink line goes up while the second instance remains at 0. Similarly, at 12:48 both instances register an event and both go up to 1. But at all times the pink line is above the red line completely covering it unless it is the case that both instances register a different number of detected events. Something that will happen very often in the production environment but difficult to generate in development.

Is there a way to overlap the two lines by making them, for example, dashed?

I have been looking in the Grafana panel options but have not been able to find it. I haven't seen anything about it in the Grafana documentation either.

Thanks in advance.